# How to change font in clion debugger window?

Tags: clion

I have a problem in my clion debugger panel, wherein the fonts of **watches ** are small and not appearing properly

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you have doesn't show the variables or "watches", select the "Debugger" tab for that. Or do you mean the tab labels themselves?

Comment: As for changing fonts, have you checked `File -> Settings` to see if there's anywhere you can change the fonts? (Hint: There are a couple of places you can change different fonts for different things)